# Set Windows 7 desktop background to none?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible in Windows 7 to set the desktop wallpaper to no bitmap at all?  Perhaps through a registry setting?

Comment: Interesting. For what purpose exactly?

Comment: Is this for a base image deployment (ie. Zero Touch Deployment)? Or to automate your manual installations (ie. autounattend.xml)? Or just a single computer, one of change (for all users or just one user??)  ?

Comment: single computer.

Comment: You can set it to a solid color. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**How to change the desktop background to a a solid colour**

1. Right click on a blank area of the desktop
2. Select **'Personalise'**
3. Click on the **'Desktop Background'** icon at the bottom of the window
4. Under **'Picture Location'** select **'Solid Colours'**
5. Select the colour of your choosing
6. Then select **'Save changes'**

[image]

You may want to use the **'More'** option to choose a more specific colour/shade.

- **Source:** [Windows 7 - How to change the desktop background to a a solid colour](http://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-7/windows-7-how-to-change-the-desktop-background-to-a-a-solid-colour)